# Stuck at level 39 of think different game android

Tags: think-different

[image]
How to solve 
3,8,4 = 44
9,7,2 = 32
8,7,? = 75

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is

> 5

This is because you should

> add the upper and left triangle, and multiply that by the right triangle, to get the middle value. This will give (8+7) * ? = 75 => ? = 5